# Excel - combine multiple columns to a single column

Tags: excel, vba

My excel sheet looks like this

```
      c1        c2      c3      c4

ROW1   abc      def      1       2

ROW2   abc      def      3       4

ROW3   klm      efg     11       5

ROW4   klm      efg     12      89
```

I want to combine the data into one single column separated by one comma for duplicate c1 entries. So excel sheet should look like this,

```
       c1        c2      c3      c4

ROW1   abc      def      1,3     2,4

ROW2   klm      efg     11,12    5,89
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code will

- Run on columns A:D on the current sheet
- Group records that are common in columns A and B togther with combined column C and column D values respectively
- runs case insensitive
- outputs to a new sheet

[image]

```
    Sub QuickCombine()
    Dim X()
    Dim Y()
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    Y = X
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        If Not objDic.exists(LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2))) Then
            objDic.Add LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2)), lngRow
        Else
            Y(lngRow, 1) = vbNullString
            Y(objDic.Item(LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2))), 3) = Y(objDic.Item(LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2))), 3) & "," & X(lngRow, 3)
            Y(objDic.Item(LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2))), 4) = Y(objDic.Item(LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2))), 4) & "," & X(lngRow, 4)
        End If
    Next

    Set ws = Sheets.Add

    ws.[a1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)) = Y
    ws.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained :) @Stuti: Brettdj was kind enough to give you everything on the plate. Show some efforts ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the excel concatenate function. Here's a link to a [good tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/concatenate-HP005209020.aspx)

Also, to deal with the duplicates, you can have excel highlight duplicate entries so they can be easily deleted. [See here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/locate-duplicates-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA001136616.aspx)

Comment: I have 50000 entries in my sheet. I want to achieve this by a code which search for duplicate entries in c1 and combine entries in c3 and c4 till then