# Combine Two Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have 2 rows in Excel sheet . All columns are identical except one.Something like 
[image]

How can I achieve this ? I am not very familiar with Pivot concept.

Any help ?

Regards.

Comment: `How can I achieve this ?` What have you tried?

Comment: I tried doing it Pivot but somehow it is always returning with sum instead of column getting combined. I am new to excel

Comment: Okay, I was using the mobile app, and apparently posted two answers where I meant to comment. Sorry for that (deleted the answers now). So I was saying: You will need to add more details about how the data is set up and what you tried already. At first glance, you need to iterate through your data to look for duplicates, so you might need VBA or at least an array formula. If you want the output to look exactly like your example, it can't be done with pivot tables as far as I know

Comment: NiH I right, you can't do it with a pivot. I know one way of doing it. Can you clarify that it's just Program_type that's changing within each ID?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want:

```
Sub QuickCombine()
    Dim X()
    Dim Y()
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    Y = X
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        If Not objDic.exists(LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2))) Then
            objDic.Add LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2)), lngRow
        Else
            Y(lngRow, 1) = vbNullString
            Y(objDic.Item(LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2))), 3) = Y(objDic.Item(LCase$(X(lngRow, 1) & X(lngRow, 2))), 3) & "," & X(lngRow, 3)
        End If
    Next

    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    [a1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)) = Y
    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612386/excel-combine-multiple-columns-to-a-single-column).