# Excel - combine, but not merge, data into a column

Tags: vba, excel

I need to combine multiple columns into one long column whilst preserving the order of the values for each column.

The key point here is that the numeric order is preserved (e.g. 1, 2, 3,..., see example below) rather than just combining columns into one long one.

Example:

```
Column A:
   1
   3       
Column B:
   2
   4    
Output: 
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

Unfortunately i've not found a macro and I'm not savvy enough with Excel to have yet found a work-around.

Would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In an empty column: `=INDEX(A:B,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+1,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+1)` in the first row and copy/drag down.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977660/excel-combine-multiple-columns-into-one-column

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612386/excel-combine-multiple-columns-to-a-single-column?s=6|1.5343

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help above! As it turns out Scott's answer worked perfectly. For posterity:

> In an empty column:
>   =INDEX(A:B,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+1,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+1) in the first row and copy/drag down.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your desired output cell press "=" key and then click on input cell. If you have many rows you can use "smart repeating function" by simply clicking in output cell and dragging it down by its right-bottom corner.